# Play video always full screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video, flowplayer

I am using flowplayer fancybox. my player works properly.now on click tollbar fullscreen button video show as full screen.

But I need when first time click on play icon then it show as fullscreen.

my current code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".infodetail").fancybox({
        'width': '80%',
        'height': '600',
        'autoScale': false,
        'transitionIn': 'none',
        'transitionOut': 'none',
        'type': 'iframe'
    }); 
    clip: {
        fullscreen : true
    }
});
```

Comment: You've got a rather obvious syntax error there.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make video go full screen programmatically. Full screen has to be a user action (i.e. They clicked for full screen)